# Diameter in metric space

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

If X is metric space, $0\not\equiv A\subset X$, A is bounded space $p \in X$, p$\not\in$ A, then diam A $\leq $ diam($A\cup \left \{ p \right \}$). Construct $A\subset R$, $p \in R$, p$\not\in$ A, so that it holds:

1. diam A = diam($A\cup \left \{ p \right \}$)
2. diam A < diam($A\cup \left \{ p \right \}$)

For the first case I was thinking, that A can be A={1,2,3} and p=2.5. Is that correct?

But I do not know about the second one.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does $0$ mean in a metric space?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I thought two points, which distance is 0, so the same points, please correct me, if I am wrong, I just want to understand it correctly

Comment: I was talking about when you wrote “$A$ should be some set, which does not contain $0$ and $p=0$”.

Comment: It makes no since that $p\in A$. If $p\in A$, then $A\cup\{p\}=A$, and therefore $\operatorname{diam}(A\cup\{p\})=\operatorname{diam}(A)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes, sorry I deleted it, because I realized it.. it should point, which does not increased the diameter.. for instance A={1,2,3} and p=1.5?

Comment: No, since $\operatorname{diam}(\{1,2,3\})=2=\operatorname{diam}(\{1,2,3,2.5\})$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can you explain me, why  p cannot be 1.5?

Comment: Because $\operatorname{diam}(\{1,2,3\})=2=\operatorname{diam}(\{1,1.5,2,3\})$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so it is correct for the first case or? I was asking about the first case when I was talking about p=1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\mathbb R$, with the usual distance, you can take, for instance, $A=\{0\}$ and $p=1$. Then $\operatorname{diam}(A)=0$ and $\operatorname{diam}(A\cup\{p\})=1$.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: but Can you explain me, why p cannot be 1.5?

Comment: @Shelley, you should compute the diameter of the spaces and show us your work.

Comment: @Simon I think that I understand it now, I just had a problem to understand the principle of it